# Wrong Timezone MongoDate in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, timezone

I inserted data in `MongoDB` via `PHP` and one field is a date. So, according to the MongoDB documentation, I used a `new MongoDate()` to do that.

In MongoDB, The date is stored such as `ISODate("2013-07-03T22:56:12Z")`. That means my timezone is `Z` (= `0Z`), so the timezone is equal to 0.
But I am in the US West coast and the timezone for my location is `8Z` (Pacific Time).

When I type `new Date()` on Mongo in the terminal, everythin g is OK. The date is `ISODate("2013-07-03T22:56:128Z")`, so this is the correct timezone `8Z`.

My development environment is Windows and MongoDB is version 2.4.4

Is there something to setup in MongoDB, in the PHP code or in the php.ini to avoid this error?

Comment: Your database dates should be in UTC; PHP should then adjust accordingly - usually with `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles')` and finally I defined the same thing directly in the php.ini `date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles;`. The date changed and now I have the correct time based on the UTC time: `ISODate("2013-07-03T23:50:00Z")`. But when I try `new Date()` in terminal, the time is the same exepted `8Z`...

Comment: Great, now you can use `gmdate()` and output the proper date/time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database dates should be in UTC; PHP should then adjust accordingly - usually with `date_default_timezone_set`. Afterwards, you can take the date from the database and plug it into `gmdate("y-m-d", strtotime($date))` for example.

Answer (score 3):

`8Z` is not a valid way to express the time zone offset in ISO8601 format.  The correct way would be:

```
2013-07-03T22:56:12-08:00
```

*Except* - for the date you provided, US Pacific Time is in Daylight Saving Time, and so `-8` is not the correct offset.  It should be `-7`.

```
2013-07-03T22:56:12-07:00
```

You should understand that many time zones have more than one offset throughout the year.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

That said, I'm uncertain as to whether or not MongoDB supports time zone offsets, or if you are required to use UTC.  Perhaps someone else can comment or answer on that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

The latest MongoDate class as a toDateTime() function which allows you to set timezone.

```
$mongoDate = new \MongoDate();
$dateTime = $mongoDate->toDateTime()->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()))
```

The other way would be to create date manually as below.

```
//2017-02-03T13:37:07.000+00:00           
$currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d', time()).'T'.date('H:i:s', time()).'.000+00:00';
$mongoDate = new \MongoDate(strtotime($currentDateTime));
```